# Mips function return a number

Tags: function, return, mips

I've been trying to learn how to program with Assembly MIPS32 on Mars.
I got a question though, i want to make a function (i don't know if that is how its called) that returns an integer.
Basically i would like to make a method that asks the user to insert a number and add that number with another one that was previously requested
This is what i came up with but i don't know how to return the value to $s2

```
New:    
    la $a0, prompt2 # Print string "Input: "
    li $v0,4 
    syscall

    li $v0,5 #Read int x
    syscall 

    jr $ra  

Add:
    j New

    add $s1, $s1, $s2 #add Int $s1 and $s2 and save them to $s1
    j loop
```

if anyone has any suggestions or fixes please respond.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common on MIPS processors to use `$v0` for function return values. Of course, you're free to come up with any calling convention you want for your own functions, but unless you have a very good reason not to I'd say stick with `$v0` for return values.

Also, to call a function you'd typically use `jal`, because that's what sets up the `$ra` register so that you later can return with `jr $ra`.
If you don't already have it, I suggest that you download *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set* and read up on how `jal` and `jr` work (or any other instruction that you feel that you don't fully understand).

So the code you described in your question could look something like:

```
New:    
    la $a0, prompt2 # Print string "Input: "
    li $v0,4 
    syscall

    li $v0,5 #Read int x
    syscall 
    # The result of syscall 5 is in $v0

    jr $ra  

Add:
    jal New
    add $s1, $s1, $v0  # add the value we just read to $s1
    j loop
```